# profile.setEnableNativeEvents(false) in selenium 3

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, webdriver

I'm on my way upgrading our tests from selenium 2 to 3. There is a final line I cannot migrate `setEnableNativeEvents(false)` in

```
FirefoxProfile profile = ...
profile.setEnableNativeEvents(false); 
webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(...);
```

I really don't know why this line was added in the past, but I'm a little afraid what happens if I remove it.

Is there a selenium 3 equivalent to this? Does it have any effect to set this to `false`, or is `false` the default?

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned you were upgrading your tests from selenium 2 to 3, I can see `setEnableNativeEvents(false)` was in practice during **`Selenium-RC`** days e.g. **`selenium-server-standalone-2.0rc2`** and **`Selenium v2.7.0`** even, as follows:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setEnableNativeEvents(true);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

The purpose of using `setEnableNativeEvents(true)` was to enable the UI elements those were disabled in Firefox [Browsers]. There were traces of issues occuring with this setting on `OS : Ubuntu 11.04` and other OS.

You can have a detailed look at [**`this thread`**](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webdriver/q2jEE_F64bo).

The current Documentation of **`FirefoxProfile`** clearly mentions about **`shouldLoadNoFocusLib()`**

### **`shouldLoadNoFocusLib()`**

The method **`shouldLoadNoFocusLib()`** returns whether the no focus library should be loaded for Firefox profiles launched on Linux, even if native events are disabled.

**`Returns`** : Whether the no focus library should always be loaded for Firefox on Linux.

Comment: `profile.setEnableNativeEvents(true);` doen't work anymore. `Cannot resolve method 'setEnableNativeEvents' in 'FirefoxProfile'` error is displayed on my IntelliJ